# SQL query oracle return more than expected result

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query to get some data:

```
select max(v.SEQUENCENO) as vmaxseq, v.CODE, v.NAMECODE, v.CODENO from smalltbl v join 
(select max(SEQUENCENO) as maxseq, CODE, CODENO from smalltbl group by CODE, CODENO) sm
on sm.CODE = v.CODE and sm.CODE = 'D50451489'
group by v.CODE, v.NAMECODE, v.CODENO;
```

But when I run, it will return more data than I expected:

[image: SQL1]

What I want is only return max of VMAXSEQ on each CODENO, something like this:

[image: SQL2]

How do I write query to get those 2 data only?

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do what you want with analytic functions.  I think the query you want is:

```
select sm.*
from (select sm.*, max(SEQUENCENO) over (partition by codeno) as maxseq
      from smalltbl sm
      where sm.CODE = 'D50451489'
     ) sm
where sequenceno = maxseq;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, thanks for your comment, but sometimes the SEQUENCENO is not same.. between CODENO, the SEQUENCENO can be bigger or smaller.. Is that your query still valid?

Comment: This query returns the rows with the row(s) with the maximum `SEQUENCENO` for each `CODENO`.  I would expect difference values of `SEQUENCENO` on a given `CODENO`.

Comment: Hi Gordon, yeah.. your query is valid! it will always return max SEQUENCENO for each CODENO.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

namecode is your problem.  Because it varies over your rows and doesn't relate directly to codeno, you're essentially getting a cartesian product.

Answer (score 0):

May be Something Like this

```
SELECT T.*
FROM smalltbl T INNER JOIN
     (
      SELECT codeno,Max(SEQUENCENO) As vmaxseq
      FROM smalltbl where CODE = 'D50451489'
      GROUP BY codeno
     ) T1 ON T.SEQUENCENO = T1.vmaxseq AND T.codeno = T1.codeno
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
select 
    vmaxseq, CODE, NAMECODE, CODENO
FROM (
    select 
        vmaxseq, CODE, NAMECODE, CODENO,
        FIRST_VALUE(vmaxseq) OVER (ORDER BY vmaxseq DESC) as firstmax   
        from (  
            select 
                max(v.SEQUENCENO) as vmaxseq, 
                v.CODE, 
                v.NAMECODE, 
                v.CODENO,               
            from smalltbl v 
                join (select max(SEQUENCENO) as maxseq, CODE, CODENO from smalltbl group by CODE, CODENO) sm
                    on sm.CODE = v.CODE and sm.CODE = 'D50451489'
        group by v.CODE, v.NAMECODE, v.CODENO
    ) 
) where firstmax = vmaxseq
```